# Sliding a view in android using animation

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i Am trying to slide a whole view from RIght to left and left to right.

Here is the code

```
Utilities.vibrate(v.getContext());               
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.leave);
                mainView.startAnimation(animation);
```

This will make it move from left to right.
Here is leave.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-90%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

It works fine however once the transition is done. It moves back to its original position. How can I make it stay at the slider position?

Comment: Did you try setting `android:fillAfter="true"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines after declaring your animation,

```
animation.setFillAfter(true);
animation.setFillEnabled(true);
```